# Eclipse using Classes in jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Hi i trying to using my own classes in a jsp file and i cant just resolve the problem, i know there is some threads about it but still i cant get it to work.

i have this class **Hej.java**

```
public class Hej {
 String a;

 public Hej(String a){
        this.a = a;
 }
 public String hej() {
        return a;
 }
}
```

and here are my jsp file **Newfile.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="Hej" %>

<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <%Hej a = new Hej(); %>
      <%=a.hej() %>
   </body>
</html>
```

my folders look like this

```
Projectname
           Java Resources
                         src
                            (default package)
                                             Hej.java
           WebContent
                     NewFile.jsp
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Does your deployment folder contains Hej.class under WEB-INF/classes directory?

Answer (score 2):

First of all dont use scriptlet for any logic to be implemented 
and secondly your code

`<%Hej a = new Hej(); %>`

fails because you have a parameterized constructor in your class by you are initializing an object without an argument try ths

```
<% Hej a = new Hej("Hello World !"); %>
```

One more thing instead of using `default package` create some package.

Example create a `package` named `mypackage` and drag the class inside it. then change the page import to something like this :

```
<%@ page import="mypackage.Hej" %>
```

Comment: Yep, can not import without a package name.