# Setting ArrayList as an attribute in servlet and accessing in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm trying   to set a Array list of String to an attribute of session in servlet, and try to access this Array list of Attributes in jsp.
But just one value(last value) access in jsp.
i want to access All list of attribute.

i searched too much here and there but i don't found about my question.

**form jsp:**

```
<form action="/CompleteServlet" method="get">
<%String completeTasks=((ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("todoList")).get(i);%>
 <input type="hidden" name="completeTasks" value="<%=completeTasks%>" />
 <input type="submit" value="Completed">
</form>
```

**from CompleteServlet :**

```
 String v=req.getParameter("completeTasks");
        HttpSession session=req.getSession();

        ArrayList<String> arrOfCompleteTask = new ArrayList<>();
        arrOfCompleteTask.add(v);
        session.setAttribute("completeTasks", arrOfCompleteTask);

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/complete.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

**form complete.jsp**

```
<%
int size=((List<String>)session.getAttribute("tryCom")).size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {%>
<%=((List<String>)session.getAttribute("tryCom")).get(i)%>``
       <%}%>
```

Comment: <%
int size=((List<String>)session.getAttribute("completeTasks")).size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {%>
<%=((List<String>)session.getAttribute("completeTasks")).get(i)%>

       <%}%>

still same erroe

Answer (score 2):

With some edits like declaring i you used in Scriptlets of *form jsp* could actually work but since I hear it's very not recommended I will offer another solution which is JSTL.

**jsfile.jsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Any title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(completeTasks) - 1}" var="index">
                <td><c:out value="${completeTasks[index]}" /></td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**form.jsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form
        action="<c:out value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}" />/CompleteServlet"
        method="get">
        <input type="text" name="new-task" value="add new task" /> <input
            type="submit" value="Completed" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Sclass.java**

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.*;

public class Sclass extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7806370535291118571L;

       public void init() throws ServletException {
          // Do required initialization
          System.out.println("init()");
       }

       public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
          System.out.println("doGet() called");

          HttpSession session= request.getSession();
          String submittedTask = (String) request.getParameter("new-task");
          System.out.println(submittedTask);
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<String> arrOfCompleteTask = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("completeTasks");

          if (arrOfCompleteTask == null)
              arrOfCompleteTask = new ArrayList<>();

          System.out.println(arrOfCompleteTask.size());

          if (arrOfCompleteTask.size() >= 1)
          {
              for (int i = 0 ; i < arrOfCompleteTask.size(); ++i) {
                  System.out.println(arrOfCompleteTask.get(i));
              }
          }

          if (submittedTask != null) 
          {
              arrOfCompleteTask.add(submittedTask);
          }

          session.setAttribute("completeTasks", arrOfCompleteTask);

          request.getRequestDispatcher("/jfile.jsp").forward(request,response);
       }

       public void destroy() {
           System.out.println("destroy()");
       }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>sname</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Sclass</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>sname</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/CompleteServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like this, where is "**i**" declared even??:

```
<form action="/CompleteServlet" method="get">
<%String completeTasks=((ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("todoList")).get(i);%>
 <input type="hidden" name="completeTasks" value="<%=completeTasks%>" />
 <input type="submit" value="Completed">
</form>
```

Scriptlets (these things: <% %>), have been discouraged against since 2010. There's a whole [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead) of reasons why you should avoid using them when you can.

What you should to do is this:

```
<form action="/CompleteServlet" method="get">
 <input type="hidden" name="completeTasks" value="${todoList}" />
 <input type="submit" value="Completed">
</form>
```

And then you either get the last value for **completeTasks** in CompleteServlet or set the last value before you send it in the form view. The latter being the simpler option. The former involves taking the completeTasks as a String and then making it an ArrayList by splitting each value, usually with a comma. With something like this:

```
String v=req.getParameter("completeTasks");
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(v.split(",")));
```