# how to iterate an ArrayList in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I create a JSP which call a java method and get an object ArrayList. I want to display the result in a table but nothing appeared. The jsp is like below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page import="SCOfetch.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>First Page</title>
<% JCOtest connection1 = new JCOtest(); %>
    <%
        ArrayList<CompanyRecord> list = new ArrayList<CompanyRecord>();
        list = connection1.step4QueryTable();
    %>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${list.rows}">
        <tr>
           <td><c:out value="${row.getValue(Name)}"/></td>
           <td><c:out value="${row.getValue(Code)}"/></td>     
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

The java code of CompanyRecord class is

```
public class CompanyRecord {
private String Code;
private String Name;
public void setValue(String value,String column)
{
    if (column.equals("Code"))
    {
        Code=value;
    }
    else 
    {
        Name=value;
    }
}

public String getValue(String column)
{

    if (column.equals("Code"))
    {
        return Code;
    }
    else 
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
}
```

what's the correct way to call an ArrayList lineitem's method? Thanks.

Comment: You should be filling in the data in a servlet before redirecting to a JSP. `ArrayList<CompanyRecord> list` is not the same Object as `${list}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find the below code for iterate ArrayList in JSP.

and please don't create the    ArrayList in JSP.please create ArrayList and set before calling JSP from the servlet.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page import="SCOfetch.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>First Page</title>
<% JCOtest connection1 = new JCOtest(); %>
    <%
        ArrayList<CompanyRecord> list = new ArrayList<CompanyRecord>();
        list = connection1.step4QueryTable();
    %>
</head>
<body>
     <c:forEach items="${list}" var="row">
       <tr>
       <td>${row.Name}</td> <!-- use variable name same like in DTO -->
       <td>${row.Code}</td>     
    </tr>
   </c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

AND please generate getter methods in CompanyRecord DTO class the only this code will work fine.

```
public class CompanyRecord {
private String Code;
private String Name;
public void setValue(String value,String column)
{
    if (column.equals("Code"))
    {
        Code=value;
    }
    else 
    {
        Name=value;
    }
}

public String getValue(String column)
{

    if (column.equals("Code"))
    {
        return Code;
    }
    else 
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public String getCode()
{
  return this.Code;
 }
public String getName()
{
  return this.Name;
 }

}
```