# ArrayList can not resolved to a type in a JSP file

Tags: java, html, jsp

In my home.JSP file, I am trying to use an ArrayList after putting the correct package name in the @page directive. The code is executing properly but I am getting error in the JSP editor window saying "ArrayList can not be resolved to a type.

here is the code snippet (Look at the last line where the array list is created that is where I am getting the error.)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.Scanner, java.util.ArrayList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor = "green"  >

hey this is coming from file
<% 
    int i  = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
    int j  = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));
    int k= i+j;

    out.println("output: "+k);
    String str = "hello";

    ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
    
%>
```

Comment: Did you configure lib correctly, i tested in my machine it work normally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead

Answer (score 0):

Try put ArrayList's import in another line, using one import by line

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Scanner" %>
```

Other issue can be there is a space between @ and "page" in first directive line