# passing ArrayList from one JSP to another using session

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, session, arraylist

```
          ArrayList<Object[]> custInfo = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); 
            while(rs.next()){
                String loginId = rs.getString("LOGIN_ID");
                String  customerId = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_ID") ;
                String  requestDate = rs.getString("REQUEST_DATE") ;
                
                 Object[] custInfo123 = {loginId, customerId, requestDate};
                 custInfo.add(custInfo123);
        }
             session.setAttribute("custInfo", custInfo);
```

in one jsp retreivedata.jsp im using arraylist to store values of result set and set session.setAttribute.
and in other jsp downloaddata.jsp im using,

```java
ArrayList<Object[]> custInfo = (ArrayList<Object[]>)session.getAttribute("custInfo");
```

but it has given me error ArrayList can not be resolved to a type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/239293/13211030

Answer (score 1):

Add import statement for ArrayList.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

**Update**

For importing ArrayList in jsp, use following syntax:

```java
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
```

Comment: Not quite correct if used in a jsp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/239293/13211030