# The import cannot be resolved in JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, types, importerror

Before posting this message I read tens of threads but with no success. I am trying to import a package into one of my JSP files and I keep getting the same error:

> The import cannot be resolved.

I believe that something is not right with my project structure. I have tried everything, from cleanup, rebuild, even creating another project from scratch.

This is the structure of my project:

[image: Project structure]

And these are the contents of my build path:

[image: Build path 1]

[image: Libraries build path]

I would greatly appreciate any kind of help, this is a big blocker right now for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead, and if you are learning on your own, don't deal with obsolete low-level operations at all; use something like Spring MVC with Boot that automatically handles all of it for you (and Thymeleaf is better than JSP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's your project structure. Your source files are not actually under the `src` folder that would be listed on the **Source** tab of the **Java Build Path** property page you're showing (you can see how it's laid out that folder's contents to resemble package names). Either move the files to where they're expected or update the **Source** tab to point to where you're actually keeping them.

Answer (score 0):

add the Java Resources/src folder to the build path or the library build path.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers, I have changed the project structure like in the image below and now it works:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).