# How do you forward attributes from a servlet to the same JSP that requested it

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

For context I have a jsp called "withdraw.jsp" that calls a servlet that processes a withdrawal. In this servlet I would like to pass a string message if the transaction is successful or not and I would like to send this message to the same jsp that called the servlet (which is still "withdraw.jsp". Here is what I did so far

```
//In the servlet
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("registeredUser/withdraw.jsp");
String error = (String)ex.getMessage();
request.setAttribute("errorMessage", error);
view.include(request,response); // i also tried forward here

//In the jsp
<% if(request.getParameter("errorMessage") != null){ %>
<p> <%=(String)request.getParameter("errorMessage")%> </p>
<% } %>
```

If I run this code, the jsp wouldn't retrieve the errorMessage since it is null despite being set as an attribute by the servlet. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing *attributes* with *parameters*.

The message is always null in your JSP because you have set an attribute in you servlet, but in your JSP you are looking for a parameter. [They are different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243754/difference-between-getattribute-and-getparameter).

Things to do:

- `.forward(...)` to your JSP using the `RequestDispatcher`;
- make sure you retrieve an attribute in your JSP;
- [do not use scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead). Depending on your JSP version you can use [EL expressions or JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

Comment: ...i swear that was getAttribute, I guess I'm too tired. Anyway, Thanks for pointing that out!