# Accessing a JSTL attribute inside a jsp code

Tags: jsp, jstl

How to access the jstl attribute "difpos" in jsp varaiable "ph".

<c:set var="difpos" value="10"/>

<%int ph = pageContext.getAttribute("difpos");
out.println(ph);%>

I am getting the error in eclipse as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to int"

I tried as below

<%int ph = (Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("difpos");

the error is cleared, but output error as

"java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"

Comment: <%String ph =(String)pageContext.getAttribute("difpos"); out.println(ph);%>

Comment: Still the same error  java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Long and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: Did you remove your original line and copy and paste my whole line?

Comment: Yeah, Now it works, Is this possible if I modify my line with method                             <c: set var="difpos" value="${Math.abs(dif)}"/>

Comment: Please look at my answer below here.

Answer (score -1):

What we are doing here is accessing a "scoped variable" in a scriptlet.
The following is an example JSP. Scriptlets are very powerful. A lot of people think that they are evil. See [JSP - What is wrong with scriptlets, and what to use instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:set var="difpos" value="10"/>
<%String ph =(String)pageContext.getAttribute("difpos"); out.println(ph);%>
<c:set var="difpos2" value="${Math.abs(12)}"/>
<%Long ph2 =(Long)pageContext.getAttribute("difpos2"); out.println(ph2);%>
<c:set var="difpos3" value="${Math.PI}"/>
<%Double ph3 =(Double)pageContext.getAttribute("difpos3"); out.println(ph3);%>
```

Output: 10 12 3.141592653589793